# Compile errors for iOS app from Flutter/IntelliJ editor?

Tags: ios, debugging, intellij-idea, ios-simulator, flutter

I'm receiving the following errors when attempting to compile my Flutter app and test on an iOS simulator.  I'm intermediate in Swift, but completely new to this type of IDE and log file info.  Please explain what these mean and how to correct them.

```
Error launching application on iPhone 6s.
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Runner/main.m:2:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
    In file included from /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
    /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:103:35: error: no type or protocol named 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey'
                options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id>*)options;
                                      ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Runner/main.m:2:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Flutter'
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.

    CompileC /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o Runner/AppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        cd /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios
        export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/Macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/Macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/Macbook/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Macbook/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/Macbook/.rvm/bin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Macbook/my_new_app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Macbook/my_new_app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Flutter -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/Macbook/my_new_app/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hhjpdwyksnzmieabrmcsddedroig/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
```

EDITED: Here is my `flutter doctor` output....

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:myApp Macbook$ flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.10.5 14F2109, locale en, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at /Users/Macbook/flutter
    • Framework revision d36e2f6191 (12 days ago), 2017-06-21 15:09:10 -0700
    • Engine revision b0dee695ec
    • Tools Dart version 1.24.0-dev.6.7

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 23.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Macbook/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-23, build-tools 23.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 7.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 7.2.1, Build version 7C1002
    • ios-deploy 1.9.1
    • CocoaPods version 1.0.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Gradle version 3.2
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.1.4)
    • Flutter plugin version 15.0
    • Dart plugin version 171.4694.29

[✓] Connected devices
    • Apple TV 1080p                            • 7C95B021-841D-48CD-A6DA-2011CF5A6CBA • ios • iOS 9.1
    • iPad 2                                    • AD0A6D3D-98A2-43DA-8E15-9833077B256C • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPad Air                                  • C3439A2D-7DB3-45A6-B00D-8B46F8CBBA99 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPad Air 2                                • 55CA03BB-398D-4029-8CD0-E0707E631F72 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPad Pro                                  • 9C658F47-2DBB-4323-B7C9-13502CCA6059 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPad Retina                               • E6232812-DD80-4B0D-8065-AD3A813E3344 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 4s                                 • 5E59506E-AB09-4157-9375-566898437500 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 5                                  • C368E301-AAB2-4A83-B513-8AFE1B9F6DCF • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 5s                                 • A77EDD0A-8BAC-4AC9-87DC-1D40BF4192A6 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 6                                  • 1D4828BC-13D2-44A5-B4B9-74B1D5E7BED2 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 6 Plus                             • 7E81F4BA-05F8-4204-BE53-38D19EC42ADF • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 6s                                 • 55766E4F-1DEB-4F98-B5FA-B3AFE959A73C • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 6s (9.2) + Apple Watch - 38mm      • 8C33DFE6-E0E3-47A1-AFAC-71820A35CDF5 • ios • iOS 2.1
    • iPhone 6s Plus                            • C10FB8C8-8213-4000-8B9E-C5CB1EA0A206 • ios • iOS 9.2
    • iPhone 6s Plus (9.2) + Apple Watch - 42mm • EBFBB3CF-77C3-4227-9E58-549EF5B3BACF • ios • iOS 2.1
    • iPhone 6s                                 • 55766E4F-1DEB-4F98-B5FA-B3AFE959A73C • ios • iOS 9.2 (simulator)

Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:myApp Macbook$
```

Comment: This might be an issue with the version of Xcode you are running. Could you please edit your question to post the results of running `flutter doctor`?

Comment: @CollinJackson added flutter doctor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same error. I updated OSX to Sierra 10.12.5 and Xcode to 8.3.3 and that resolved.

Comment: Do you think this will work with El Capitain and Xcode 8.2?

Comment: If anyone else was wondering....   El Capitain and XCode 8.2.1 work fine.  I was able to get my project to load from XCode, but couldn't update my `flutter doctor` to recognize the new version.  Please leave a comment if you know how to get this done.